# Making a promotional video for G&FH SE?

Tags: discussion, publicity

What do you folks think about creating a short promotional video for the site? It could be posted to YouTube, and then easily shared on social media such as Facebook and Twitter. It seems that videos are more and more becoming the media of choice, where static images just don't get enough attention.

I'm thinking a short video, perhaps 30 seconds to a minute. Obviously we would want it to look and sound professional, and it would take a lot of work. I have some amateur video-editing skills so would be willing to take a lead on this, but am also happy to yield to anyone with more experience in this type of thing.

We would have to check with the StackExchange higher ups if this would be ok to do, as I'm sure there are policies regarding trademarks etc. for outside advertising. I don't know if since we are still in beta there would be any objections. If there is enough support here I can make a post over on the main Meta.

No real concrete ideas yet. Please post any video ideas or concerns/objections/support below.

Comment: My first thought is that this could be a great idea. It would be worth doing some research first on whether any other SE site has done this to see how they presented their site.

Comment: For some ideas on structuring a promo video we could look at https://info.udemy.com/perfect-promo which is where I publish eLearning video courses.

Comment: For ideas on a promo video, I would especially like to hear from @lkessler since he had to produce a video for his RootsTech Innovator Showdown submission.

Comment: If we can't get permissions to do a video that shows the site itself, could we make a video about *how to ask a good question* and mention Genealogy.SE in the audio track?

Comment: @JanMurphy I've not checked but I would be very surprised if SE had any objection to us promoting one of its sites via a video that showed it.

Comment: @PolyGeo we would have to be careful to choose a question / answer that did not have images of historical records, since we don't have the permission to include those images in a presentation.  Otherwise we could expose SE to legal liability. We really, really don't want to go there.

Comment: List of questions/concerns is growing, so before taking this further I've posted on main Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294553/making-a-promotional-video-for-a-stackexchange-site

Comment: Anyone who is a user at [meta.se] and wants a bounty of 50 there just needs to make provide an answer on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294553/making-a-promotional-video-for-a-stack-exchange-site

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea.

I think that 30 seconds to a minute may be too short to get the compelling reasons why the viewer of this promo video should take the next steps of visiting G&FH SE and then asking/answering their first question there.  I'm thinking that 2-3 minutes may be more able to do that, but lets see if we can get 30 seconds to a minute first, and then see if we need more time.

I think it could include about 2-3 site users saying briefly why they use this site as part of their research into their genealogy and family history.  These would be users of different "types", perhaps seasoned professional, ultra-keen amateur, etc.

The only SE promo video that I have found so far is not for a site, but instead for [Winter Bash 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U&feature=youtu.be).  Nevertheless, it may give some ideas on length and standards that may be appropriate.